# How to reenginering web application from Spring MVC to JSF?

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-mvc

What can I use for data access, timers etc? Seam, jBoss, GlassFish? Or simply Tomcat + JSF + Hibernate/JPA?
I need add just one JSF component to Spring MVC pages but I am afraid I must rewrite whole web app to jsf and drop Spring.

Answer (score 0):

I see [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/sample_application_using_jsf_spring) an example about using jsf with Spring.

Also take a look [here](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/232-integrating-spring-web-flow-with-jsf-1.html).

Maybe it's useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

jbo, If you are just interested in replacing your view layer, you need not switch to hibernate/jpa etc.. JSF can co-exist with spring MVC. Need not discard any of you business objects and DAO's. 
Better option is to consider spring-webflow. It is built on spring-mvc. Also support jsf views

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2008/jw-11-intro-to-swf2.html

http://www.springsource.org/webflow

http://www.springsource.org/webflow-samples